Continuity and Axiom of Choice
Note: There is another question with the same title, but it is essentially different.
The usual definition of continuity of a real-valued function of a single real variable:
Definition 1: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$
An alternative definition of continuity:
Definition 2: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ if there is a function $b:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that:

If $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<b(\delta)$
$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}b(\delta)=0$

If $f$ is continuous at $a$ in the second sense, then it is continuous in the first sense; this can be proven without using the Axiom of Choice.
But if $f$ is continuous at $a$ in the first sense, and we want to construct a function $b$ to show that it is also continuous in the second sense, we have to use the Axiom of Choice...right?
Question: Is there a model of the real numbers where there is a function which is continuous in the first sense but not the second?

You might want to allow your function $b$ to possibly take value $\infty$, as otherwise the function $f$ can be continuous at $a$ but behave wildly outside a small interval around $a$, in which case if $\delta$ is larger than the radius of that small interval, you cannot guarantee the existence of a non-infinite $b(\delta)$.

Oh right, thanks!

No. The axiom of choice is not needed to go from the first definition of continuity to the second. Indeed, assume $f$ is continuous at $a$ in the first sense. Then we may define,
$$b(\delta) = \delta + \sup_{x: |x-a| < \delta} |f(x)-f(a)|$$
It is easy to check that $b(\delta)$ satisfies the conditions in Definition $2$, so $f$ is continuous in the second sense as well.

I don't know why I didn't think of that! Also, doesn't $b(\delta)=\sup |f(x)-f(a)|$ suffice? Why the extra $\delta$ term?

@semisimpleton If $b(\delta)$ is just the supremum, then you only get $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq b(\delta)$ instead of the strict inequality you required in your Definition $2$. Also, the supremum could be $0$, which is not in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\cup{\infty}$. So, adding $\delta$ is just a technicality, to satisfy those two requirements.
